# use a powershell task in azure devops pipeline that reads a json file

Tags: powershell, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to use a Powershell script, that runs locally on my Windwos machine in an Azure Devops Pipeline. I can call the ps1 File just fine, but then I get an error when the script wants to read a JSON File, that is in the same directory (locally) / repository (devops).

```
$CurrentFolder = $pwd.Path

$Some_JSON_File = Join-Path $CurrentFolder 'SomeFile.json'
$JSON_Content = Get-Content $Some_JSON_File | ConvertFrom-Json
...
```

The error message, that I get in the pipeline task is:

```
Get-Content : Cannot find path 'D:\a\1\s\SomeFile.json' because it does not exist.
At D:\a\1\s\some_powershell.ps1:16 char:17
+ $JSON_Content = Get-Content $Some_JSON_File | ConvertFrom- ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (D:\a\1\s\SomeFile.json:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundExcept 
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

I probably have to load the Json File, but I can't figure out how. Any help appreciated, thanks!

Edit adds the pipeline steps:

```
steps:
  - checkout: self
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: 'Powershell task'
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: '.\replace_placeholders.ps1'
```

Comment: Are you *sure* the file is there? What have you done to confirm it?

Comment: Yes, the file is in the repository, and it's in the same folder as the Powershell script (which is accessible). My pipeline script looks like this:

steps:
  - checkout: self
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: 'Powershell task'
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: '.\some_powershell.ps1'

Comment: That half-answered my question. What steps have you taken to confirm the file is *actually* present where you think it is? Are you running on an OS with a case-sensitive file system? If so, did you confirm that the case is correct?

Comment: As @DanielMann mentioned, verify that the file is actually in place. Then you'll probably have an answer why the file can't be found. Do a (Get-ChildItem).FullName on the folder that you expect to find the file.

Comment: When I run the Powershell script locally, on my windows machine, it runs fine, and finds the file. I'm encountering the problem only, when I call the (same) Powershell script in an Azure Devops Pipeline with said Powershell task. So yes, the file is probably not present there, but I don't have a clue on how to make that happen...

Comment: @DanielZimmermann What works and doesn't work on your local machine is **irrelevant**. Check what's happening *during your pipeline's run*.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the missing file was not in the repository. After adding it there, it worked.